# Force button to appear below content IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I'm having some issues with a button in IE7. In everything else the button appears like this:
[image: Correct]

However, in IE7 the button appears like this.
[image: Incorrect]

I've tried to put together a jsfiddle with the code that is affecting the overall form and the fiddle seems okay (even though it is missing the image references) so I don't understand why IE7 is throwing a fit with this button and making it appear on the right of my content.

```
 JsFiddle Code
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jezzipin/vBf6U/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fix the issue in IE 7

```
div.links {
    clear: both !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
```

In the stylesheet, icams_specific.css find this section and replace all of it with this:

```
div.widget-container > div.search > form.search > div#search_links > input.button {
background-color: #E7E7E8;
background-image: url("/incl/images/search.png");
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
border: medium none;
cursor: pointer;
height: 35px;
margin-left: 257px;
margin-top: -35px;
padding: 0;
transition: all 0.25s linear 0s;
vertical-align: top;
width: 38px;
}
```

To move the search button left right, change `margin-left: 257px;` to the required value.

You will also need to keep the change made to div.links above

Comment: Basically, we have an underlying system that provides the HTML and some standard styling from out of the database. There will be contradictions in the CSS because the only control I have over the styling is through the use of one modifiable CSS stylesheet that must add styles but also where necessary overwrite the standard style of the system to skin the system to appear like a clients site. If you notice, these lines are overwritten (or should be) by    div.links {
    clear: none !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

Comment: If you can link me to the site, I'm sure I can be of more help.

Comment: That also breaks the search bar on the right hand side so that is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

If i open this one in IE it works fine for me. any way give

```
<div class="logindetails password" style="clear:both;">
```

to the above div.

Comment: the above code not necessary. but your html working fine. i checeked in my local. Have you clear the cache?

Comment: It seems to work in the JSFiddle but not on the actual site I'm working on.